# How to set Application Icon in QT on WinCE?

Tags: qt, windows-mobile

Please help me with solution of how to set the app icon for `exe` file on windows mobile platform? It means that icon should displays in explorer, task manager and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-windows) might be of helpful to you.

Comment: does it applicable for windows mobile? because the topic is "Setting the Application Icon on Windows" if you follow your link

Comment: @ Sergey, Yeah it's for Windows only and am not used with Windows Mobile. But I guess it will be similar..

Comment: @ Sergey, From Docs, *On top of all the tools and API and class libraries that Qt offers, Qt for Windows CE provides you with added functionality for an optimized embedded development environment.* - which means that **you can use all the normal Qt APIs**. So it should work. Give it a try..

Answer (score 0):

QApplication::setWindowIcon

Comment: QApplication::setWindowIcon is set icon for running application. I need to set icon even my application wasn't started (Explorer, Start Menu icon and so on).

Answer (score 0):

**In Qt 4**, you need to create a .rc file like this:

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "myIcon.ico"
```

You should add this to your .pro file :

```
win32: RC_FILE += MyApp.rc
```

**In Qt 5** there is an automated process for setting an icon to the application executable file .

You can just add the following to the .pro file:

```
win32: RC_ICONS = myIcon.ico
```

Also store the .ico file in your application's source code directory.

Note that this is only for Windows. There are other ways to set application icon in Linux and Mac.